# How do you `use:` a bound component value in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the following:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte'
  let component: MyComponent
</script>

<MyComponent bind:this={component} />

<input use:component.inputActions />
```

But this produces the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inputActions')

MyComponent.js contains the following export:

```
<script lang="ts">
export function inputActions(node: HTMLElement) {
  // ...
}
</script>
```

However it works fine if `inputActions` is defined in that same component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`component` will only be defined after the respective component is mounted.

You could wrap the `<input>` using the action in an `{#if component}` to work around this. Though I question whether the action really needs to be defined on a component instance...

Comment: How else could I define it if not by a component instance? The only ways I could find to use exported things are 1. converting it to plain js or ts, 2. changing the context to module, 3. defining a component instance like I have here.

Comment: Most actions are just plain JS/TS, so I usually define them in separate JS/TS files. There has to be a good reason for having a component instance dependency like this (i.e. accessing private component state or something like that). Even then, it probably could be written differently so all dependencies are just passed in as required.

Comment: The function needs to access around 10 values from a store, which would have to be dependency injected into several functions, which I thought would make the code more complicated. Although I'm reading now that you can access the store values from javascript, so that will likely be a better option.

Comment: If you have many functions that all have the same dependency, you can also wrap everything in another function or class, providing the dependency only once.